# Local gauge invariance of field's homotopy class? Every map $S^2\rightarrow \mathrm{group } G$ is homotopic to a constant map?

Tags: mathematical-physics, homotopy-theory, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

In a discussion of a gauge field theory with gauge group $G$, someone says we can use a celebrated result of *E. Cartan* to show the gauge invariance of matter field's homotopy class. And **Cartan's result is that every map $S^2\rightarrow G$ is homotopic to a constant map**, and since we are assuming G to be connected this constant may be taken to be the identity element of G. I reckon that this argument makes sense.

But could you tell me more about this Cartan's theorem (proof, explanation or so) or at least, where I can find some introduction of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is that if $G$ is any Lie group, then its second homotopy group $\pi_2(G)$ vanishes. You can find a number of proofs and references to proofs at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8957/homotopy-groups-of-lie-groups).